# How do I rsync exclude a specific directory

Tags: rsync

If I have the following directory structure:

```
foo/
    foo.txt
bar/
    foo/
        hum.txt
```

how do I exclude the top-level `foo` directory without excluding `bar/foo`? When I run:

`rsync --exclude-from exclude-file ...`

and the contents of `exclude-file` is merely:

```
foo
```

*both* directories are excluded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, the answer is blindingly obvious. `exclude-file` should be written as:

```
/foo
```